# Hide WooCommerce COD payment for specific product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, taxonomy-terms

I try do hide "Cash On Delivery" payment (cod) in a wordpress add_filter instruction for a list of products categories

I have a debug trace that writes that a boolean variable is true
but , with the instructions below , the unset is not active
Do you know why ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'remove_cod_payment_gateways_for_some_taxonomy_products',15);

function remove_cod_payment_gateways_for_some_taxonomy_products($available_gateways)
{

//...
    if (in_array($term->term_id, $category_ids)){
        var_dump("found");
        $unset = true;
        break;
    }
//...
    // I am sure $unset == true and found is displayed on the page!!
    if ($unset == true) unset($available_gateways['cod']);
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

The cod Payment remains visible ; I do not unserstand why
Have you an idea ?

If I suppress if ($unset == true) , the cod payment is hidden... but I know that the condition is true . So I really do non understand

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right way to hide "COD" (Cash On Delivery) payment gateway if there are cart items belonging to specific product categories... Try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'hide_cod_payment_gateway_based_on_categories', 20 );
function hide_cod_payment_gateway_based_on_categories( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Only for checkout page
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return $payment_gateways;

    // Here define your product categories term Ids, slugs or names.
    $targeted_terms = array('hoodies');

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( isset($payment_gateways['cod']) && has_term($targeted_terms, 'product_cat', $item['product_id']) ) {
            unset($payment_gateways['cod']);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $payment_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.